# Bootstrap nav bar with home icon issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to display home icon on bootstrap nav bar. i follow this link http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=pills-nav-with-icons

my html looks like

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">All Parts</a></li>                                

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
```

but still no luck. my home icon does not look good. jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/0gjw5rzg/1/

Comment: why negative vote without any reason said here.

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue here, what's the problem?

Comment: You're trying to do different things it seems, the link you posted, points to a pills nav, whereas your code is using the Navbar, these are two separate things in Bootstrap. Which one would you like to use?

Comment: Do you want to add icon with text like in first example?

Comment: when i was testing my code then some reason home icon was not showing and that is the reason i post the issue here. now all fine. if possible remove negative vote. thanks all

Comment: Make sure to mark an answer, if someone helped. Otherwise you could probably ditch the question altogether.

Comment: my code was working fine. by mistake i post this issue. ignore this post.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the Home and the Icon to be in the same navigation item add "Home" after the `span` tag.

```
<li class="active">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home
  </a>
</li>
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0gjw5rzg/5/